# Publishing multiple Endpoints on Wildfly Server

Tags: wildfly

I want to create programatically web services on Wildfly server. I have defined WebService URLs in the configuration file. So I run two endopoints in the following way:

**Endpoint.publish("http://0.0.0.0:8080/ws/export1", new ImlementationClass());
Endpoint.publish("http://0.0.0.0:8080/ws/export2", new ImlementationClass());**

but I cannot invoke any of the webservice method. I can see error message "HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL". Also adding "?wsdl" suffix does not show WSDL definition.

I don't want to use default mechanism beacuse I read webservice URL from the configuration file. Can I use above methods to run webservices on the Wildfly? Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Is your `ImlementationClass` annotated with @WebService annotation ?

Comment: Yes, This class has @WebService annotation